# Installing and configuring Xero certificates, Azure web apps

Tags: azure, x509certificate, xero-api

I'm trying to get Xero Partner authorization working on my Azure web app. When I got the token from Xero team, they directed me to their documentation page "Partner Applications with IIS". There are several steps that must be followed in order to properly install and configure certificates on IIS. The thing is, I don't have the access to IIS server running my Azure web apps because of the shared environment and isolation organization. I was digging for answers and found this:"Your only solution is to bring up an azure VM. Then load the certificate into IIS on the VM. You can then write a wcf service to send your xero requests from the azurewebsite to the VM."

Has anyone had this kind of problem? Did you find a way to complete the installation and configuration process without setting-up a Virtual Machine?

Comment: Having the exact same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519068/x509-certificates-on-azure-web-app. If you get anywhere with your issue, please share the solution.